# How do I rescale the X axis in MATLAB's plot function?

Tags: matlab, plot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing scaling of MATLAB Figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456027/changing-scaling-of-matlab-figure)

I have an m-size vector f. By calling `plot(f)` MATLAB plots a graph of x=1..m as a function of f:

[image: f as a function of 1,2,...,m]

I would still like a graph of f as a function of 1..m, but I want the numbers on the x axis to be 5,15,25,...,95  (`fake_x = 5:10:95`).

In other words: I want the graph to be exactly the same (f as a function of x=1..m), but the x axis should be `fake_x`, not x.

Comment: Duplicates: [Changing scaling of MATLAB Figure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456027/changing-scaling-of-matlab-figure), [How to change the format of the numbers displayed on an axis in a MATLAB plot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727797/how-to-change-the-format-of-the-numbers-displayed-on-an-axis-in-a-matlab-plot)

Comment: @gnovice: Gah! And I even checked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set(gca,'XTick',[5 15 25 35 45 55 65 75 85 95])
```

Or something like this.

look up "tick" in the help documentation.
the set(gca... function is very helpful in customizing plots.

hope this helps